# Thrust vector with custom data type

Tags: cuda, copy, thrust

I am using the thrust library for my project and ran into the following problem:

I have a struct called box defined as

```
typedef struct {
    int coord[4];
    float h;
} box;
```

and am now trying to copy data from a device_vector of boxes to a host_vector of boxes:

```
thrust::device_vector<box> d_boxes(100);
thrust::host_vector<box> h_boxes;
thrust::copy(d_boxes.begin(), d_boxes.end(), h_boxes.begin());
```

But this throws the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
>   what():  invalid argument

If I do the same with int instead of box, it works fine.
Unfortunately, the documentation does not seem to have any example of vectors of custom data types.

What did I miss?

Comment: You don't need to call `thrust::copy`, just assign `d_boxes` to `h_boxes` in its initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thrust::copy` doesn't automatically resize vectors for you (actually no thrust algorithms do.)

So this is an empty vector, not large enough to hold 100 objects:

```
thrust::host_vector<box> h_boxes;
```

Try this instead:

```
thrust::host_vector<box> h_boxes(100);
```

As pointed out by @JaredHoberock, an alternate realization could be:

```
thrust::device_vector<box> d_boxes(100);
thrust::host_vector<box> h_boxes = d_boxes;
```

In this case, the constructor for `h_boxes` creates it with a size appropriate to hold the number of elements in `d_boxes` (as well as performing the device -> host data copy.)

Comment: Ha. Didn't know that. Thanks :)